# @Binding value change not being recognised in parent view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a connected a `@Binding` variable called `showCodeMessage` between my parent view `LiveView` and its child view `NewTimer`.

```
struct LiveView: View {
    @ObservedObject var countdown: CountDown
    @State var showCodeMessage: Bool = false {
        didSet(val){
            print("changed: \(val)") // doesn't print
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            NewTimer(countdown: self.countdown, showCodeMessage: $showCodeMessage)
            if self.showCodeMessage { // doesn't show
                MessageWithButton()
                   .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                   .padding(.top, 10)
                   .padding(20)
                   .opacity(self.messageOpacity2)
            }
         
        }
    }
}

struct NewTimer: View {
    @ObservedObject var countdown: CountDown
    @Binding var showCodeMessage: Bool
    @State var codeSent = false
    @State var inBackground = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Timer")
                .onAppear{
                    self.countdown.secondsLeft = 600
                    self.countdown.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){ _ in
                        self.countdown.secondsLeft -= 1
                        // At the 9:00 minute mark, show code message
                        if self.countdown.secondsLeft <= 595 && !showCodeMessage && self.inBackground == false {
                            print("Show code message: \(self.countdown.secondsLeft)")
                            self.showCodeMessage = true
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
    }
    
}
```

However, when I perform `self.showCodeMessage = true` - the change doesn't register in my parent view. It doesn't even detect that a change has been made.

Any idea why?

EDIT: Added other classes/structs below

```
class CountDown: ObservableObject {
    init(secondsLeft: Int){
        self.secondsLeft = secondsLeft
    }
    @Published var secondsLeft: Int
    var timer: Timer?
    func start(){
        // Reset epoch
        UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "epoch")
    }
    func stop(){
        self.timer?.invalidate()
    }
    func performAtEnd(action: @escaping () -> Void){
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){ _ in
            self.secondsLeft -= 1
            print("performAtEnd() \(self.secondsLeft)")
            if (self.secondsLeft == 0){
                print("action() \(self.secondsLeft)")
                action()
                self.timer?.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MessageWithButton: View {
    let text: String
    let color: Color
    let hasButton: Bool = false
    @Binding var showCode: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("\(self.text)")
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Bold", size: 16))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(11)
            MessageButton(showCode: $showCode).padding(5)
        }
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .foregroundColor(self.color)
        )
    }
}

struct MessageButton : View {
    @Binding var showCode: Bool
//    @AppStorage("codeResult") var codeResult = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "codeResult") ?? ""
    @AppStorage("codeResult") var codeResult = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "codeResult") ?? ""
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {self.clickedCode()}){
            Text("\(buttonText())")
                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Bold", size: 18))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(10)
        }
        .background(Color("LightBlack"))
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .padding(.trailing, 5)
    }
    
    func buttonText() -> String {
        if self.showCode { return "HIDE" }
        return "ENTER"
    }
    
    func clickedCode(){
        // Remove 'incorrect' from codeResult so Code input can show again
        self.codeResult = ""
        print("clickedcode()")
        self.showCode.toggle()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add `CountDown` and `MessageWithButton` classes - make your code reproducible.

Comment: Added in edit @pawello2222

Comment: Your code works in Xcode 11.6, iOS 13.6. It looks like you're using Xcode 12, so this might be some bug in the beta version. Just note you can't add `didSet` to `@State` variables. And with your amount of code it might be better to use a ViewModel class and move all logic there.

Comment: `didSet` should not be called on State in this case, everything else works fine with Xcode 12b5 / iOS 14.

Comment: Yes you're all right - it works fine. It was just hidden. Thankyou.